# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/SafeBrowsingResponse

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

I am facing this exception

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/SafeBrowsingResponse" while implementing webview in android.

I have searched for an appropriate solution over the web but didn't find anything useful.

My XML file is this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_title" />


        <im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
            android:id="@+id/mWebview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my java code against this XML is

```
public class PaymentActivity extends ParentActivity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {

//    private WebView webView;

private AdvancedWebView mWebView;
ProgressDialog dialog;
UserModel userModel;
SessionManager sessionManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setActionBar("Payment");
    sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
    userModel = sessionManager.getUserInformation();

    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.mWebview);
    mWebView.setListener(this, this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    String planType = getIntent().getStringExtra("planType");

    String url = "www.google.com";

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    mWebView.loadUrl(url);


}


@Override
public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) {

    dialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(String url) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) {

}

@Override
public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) {

}

@Override
public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

}
```

My compileSdkVersion is `26`, minSdkVersion is `17` and targetSdkVersion is `22`. I am testing this code on `Android 8.0 API 26`.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps if you can give more context on where and how you are using it, you might get a answer. I faced the same issue earlier today and I'm testing on API 22. My problem wasn't the `SafeBrowsingResponse` class, but passing the wrong file path (I tested with a local file).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/SafeBrowsingResponse), this class was added in Android level 27.  You are trying to use it on level 26 test platform.  Naturally, the platform cannot load the class ... that it doesn't know about.

Comment: Any way to use this on API 26 or less?

Comment: A brief search didn't give me any mention of a backport of this class, so I think that the answer is no.

Comment: "you are using it..." The application doesn't user the method directly, it calls webview/webkit though, which in turn calls that method. Could it be an indication that webkit itself is using the worng level APIs?